# how to show data from 2 models in django with one to many relashion in template

Tags: python, django

Hello i have 2 classes in my model:

```
class MO (models.Model):
    many variables


class PhotoMO (models.Model):
    mo = models.ForeignKey(MO, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    photo = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='img/photo/%Y/%m/'
    )
```

my views for template

```
class MOListView(DetailView):
    template_name = 'main_site/mo_view.html'
    model = models.MO
```

with template :

```
{% block content %}
    <h1>{{ mo.name }}</h1>
    <h3>{{ mo.phone_number }}</h3>
    <h3>{{ mo.email_mo }}</h3>
    <h3>{{ mo.adress_mo }}</h3>
{% for photos in mo.photomo.set.all %}
    <img src="{{ photos.photo.url }}" alt="no img">
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

How can I display all the pictures from PhotoMO that refer to a specific entry in MO. With my "for" it dosen't work

Comment: you can use prefetch_related

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related

Comment: The answer below is not a solution to the question, in order to view data it should be configured in the view.

Comment: rarblack, you about get_context_data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{% for photo in mo.photomo_set.all %}

     <img src="{{ photo.photo.url }}" alt="none">

{% endfor %}
```

need to use mo.photomo_set.all

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the back relation:

```
class PhotoMO (models.Model):
    mo = models.ForeignKey(MO, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='photomo')
```

Then migrate the database to be able to access `photomo`.

Kind regards.